# Rust failed to downcast_ref from trait object extended from Any

Tags: rust

[Here is the Rust Playground of the example code.](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=34a45ef51aed98ce4c26e3390afae780)

```rust
use std::any::Any;

pub trait MemorizedOutput: Any {
    fn as_any(&self) -> &dyn Any;
}

impl<T: Any> MemorizedOutput for T {
    fn as_any(&self) -> &dyn Any {
        self
    }
}

fn main() {
    let a = Box::new(1i32) as Box<dyn MemorizedOutput>;
    println!("{}", a.as_any().downcast_ref::<i32>().unwrap());
}
```

Why is the above code panic at `unwrap()`.

Comment: There's an interesting question to be answered here, and I don't offhand know why this doesn't work. But it's worth keeping in mind that what you're doing here, while academically interesting, is very Java-like and would absolutely not be idiomatic Rust. Generally, in Rust, most of your code can get by with static dispatch and you occasionally dip into trait objects when needed. The language provides no built-in mechanism to go from a trait object *back* to the concrete type simply because there's never a good reason to do so. Even if your code snippet worked, it would be a massive code smell.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Box<dyn MemorizedOutput>` implements `Any`, so it is covered by the blanket implementation of `MemorizedOutput`. As per https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/expressions/method-call-expr.html, Rust will prefer methods implemented on `Box<dyn MemorizedOutput>` before it the dereferenced type `dyn MemorizedOutput`. So `a.as_any()` is actually `<Box<dyn MemorizedOutput> as MemorizedOutput>::as_any(&a)`, which obviously cannot be downcasted into `i32`.

Comment: Thanks. I figured it out with the help of my friends. And the cause is just what you said. To bypass the blanket implementation. I use `as_ref()` to convert `Box` to a reference, which is a type not implementing `Any`. Thank you!

Comment: In fact, `(*some_box).as_any()` also works